# what magic methods to implement in pickle -able class?

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

Class Sketch(dict) reconstituted (unpickle) with the error (see the code below):

```
Failed example:
    s2 = pickle.loads(b)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.9/doctest.py", line 1336, in __run
        exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
      File "<doctest __main__[10]>", line 1, in <module>
        s2 = pickle.loads(b)
      File "/home/vlz/Documents/py31eg/image/pickle_lab.py", line 66, in __setitem__
        if color != self.background:
    AttributeError: 'Sketch' object has no attribute 'background'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of  12 in __main__
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

That's where I started. His counterpart Sketch_has_dict(object) pickle/unpickle -ed successfully (in the same test below).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
>>> s = Sketch_has_dict()
>>> for y in range(2):
...     for x in range(3):
...             s[(x, y)] = 'yellow'
...
>>> import pickle
>>> b = pickle.dumps(s, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
>>> s2 = pickle.loads(b)
>>> len(s2)
6
>>> s = Sketch()
>>> for y in range(2):
...     for x in range(3):
...             s[(x, y)] = 'yellow'
...
>>> import pickle
>>> b = pickle.dumps(s, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
>>> s2 = pickle.loads(b)
>>> len(s2)
6
"""


class Sketch_has_dict:
    def __init__(self, width=3, height=2, background='red'):
        self.color = set()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.background = background
        self.pixels = {}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pixels)

    def __getitem__(self, coord):
        return self.pixels.get(coord, self.background)

    def __setitem__(self, coord, color):
        if color != self.background:
            self.pixels[coord] = color

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.pixels)


class Sketch(dict):
    def __new__(cls):
        s = super().__new__(cls)
        s.colors = set()
        s.width = 3
        s.height = 2
        s.background = 'red'
        return s

    def __init__(self, width=3, height=2, background='red'):
        self.colors = set()
        self.width = width
        self.background = background
        self.height = height
        super(Sketch, self).__init__()

    def __setitem__(self, coord, color=None):
        if color != self.background:
            self.colors.add(color)
        super(Sketch, self).__setitem__(coord, color)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The test passed when I added __new__ method to Sketch(dict) class. I hardcoded the initial attr values. When and with what args __new__ is called while reconstituting the object is unclear to me.

When I need pickle -able class, what magic methods shall I implement? Looks like __init__ isn't called while reconstituting (pickle.loads) both instances. What are the steps pickle.loads() goes through when reconstituting an object?

Using Python 3.9.2, Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

PS
I reread my question. Sounds unclear. To rephrase: how shall I refactor my Sketch class to make it suitable for pickle.dumps, pickle.loads ?

Comment: As a side note, if you think you really have to subclass `dict`, it's advisable to at least user [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict) instead of subclassing `dict` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want or need `__new__` here; it happens to work (by convincing the pickling machinery that the class has strict construction-time invariants), but it's overkill, and leads to slightly slower code, for no real benefit (in general, `__new__` is for immutable types that *must* know their state at construction time; mutable types like `dict` don't use it).

The problem you have here is that the default pickling is based on what `dict` is defined to do, and it happens to do the `dict`-based reconstruction *before* the rest of your state is set. This wouldn't usually be an issue, but you have a `__setitem__` that only works when `self.background` is set, and it isn't set during the default `dict` unpickling sequence.

You can fix this by overriding the default pickling sequence:

```
class Sketch(dict):
    # No __new__, __init__ and __setitem__ unchanged

    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), (self.width, self.height, self.background), self.colors, None, iter(self.items())
    def __setstate__(self, colors):
        self.colors = colors
```

`__reduce__` is the top-level pickling special method. The return value is a `tuple`, the components of which [are documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__). In particular, we're saying "When recreating this object:

1. (First two elements of `tuple`) Call `Sketch` with my current values of `self.width, self.height, self.background` as arguments first (establishing the `background` attribute up-front),
2. (Third element) Pass this (`self.colors`) to `__setstate__` to recover non-construction related state
3. (Fifth element) Then take these key/value pairs and set them normally, going through `__setitem__` (since `self.background` is established up-front now, these calls will work)

We then define `__setstate__` as well, which is trivial; we returned `self.colors` in `__reduce__`, we'll be passed the reconstructed `set`, so we just attach it to the `self.colors` attribute as normal.

---

Now, all that said, I'd strongly recommend sticking to your `Sketch_has_dict` design. The question to ask yourself for subclassing is "Is a [Child] a [Parent]?" So in this case, the question is "Is a Sketch a dictionary?" That doesn't hold logically, and you'll likely find yourself running into other problems caused by inheriting *all* of `dict`'s behaviors, not just the specific ones you care about. Stick with composition, not inheritance, for cases like these.

Comment: Inheritance turned out is neither clearer, nor shorter than composition. I'll continue with composition.